# ACF checkbox on click on the checkbo new field should be added

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

firstly i want  to make the same fields like this link https://teamemsoft.com/staging/profile/mark-monteleone/.
and then I want that when I check on the checkbox a new field should be added below the checkbox like this is what I am trying to do

**ACF checkbox on check on the  checkbox new field should be added** 
please help me that what should I can do?
and how is this possible

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

You first need to list down all the form fields and then you should use jquery to hide/show the fields based on clicking the checkbox.

As per my understanding, I have created a JSfiddle. This will work as you expected.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
$(".heynow2_div").hide();
$("#check1").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".heynow2_div").show(300);
    } else {
        $(".heynow2_div").hide(200);
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="check_div">
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" value="00">
<label for="check1"> 00</label><br>
</div>
<div class="heynow1_div">
<label for="heynow"> Hey Now</label><br>
<input type="text" id="heynow" name="heynow" value="">
</div>
<div class="heynow2_div">
<label for="heynow2"> Hey Now2</label><br>
<input type="text" id="heynow2" name="heynow2" value="">
</div>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rajeevRF/1gyuj8zb/10/